# How to increse php file size upload size limit

Tags: php, html, wcf

I am using wcf service in php through nusoap classes. My requirement is to upload a minimum file size of 10MB and max filesize upto 32MB. I have changed max_input_time, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size properties of PHP.ini, PHP.ini-developer and PHP.ini-production. But still it is not responding.

The page supports file size upto 254kb but if filesize exceeds the page execution doesn't stop for long time and shows error **maximum page execution time 30sec exceeds**

How to solve the problem. I searched lot but still no luck.

Thanks, 
Aviansh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bandwidth is not catching up with the

```
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
```

Change these values to higher.